# Book of Why: $p(L | D, Z)$ explanation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality

In the Book of Why by Judea  Pearl (page 14) he says to work out the effect a drug (D) will have on a patients lifespan (L) taking into account other factors (Z) can be calculated as P(L | D, Z) x P(Z)

What is the purpose of multiplying by P(Z) when trying to calculate the effect of D on L?

Comment: Others will be willing to help you, but you're going to have to give more context and detail for your question before they can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, *if* the event of taking the drug is *independent* of the other factors, then :

$$\mathsf P(L, Z\mid D)=\mathsf P(L\mid D,Z)~\mathsf P(Z)$$

And so, by the Law of Total Probability:

$$\mathsf P(L\mid D)=\sum_{Z\in\mathcal Z}\mathsf P(L\mid D,Z)~\mathsf P(Z)$$

Where $\mathcal Z$ is the set of other factors.

For each $Z$ in $\mathcal Z$, $\mathsf P(L\mid D,Z)$ measures the effect of taking the drug among a 'test' group with specified other factors, and $\mathsf P(Z)$ measures the proportion of subjects with those other factors in the 'wild'.   So therefore $\mathsf P(L\mid D)$ predicts the average effect of taking the drug among the 'wild'